# re.split() doesn't split after some characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a string,no matter what i do, the string is not splitting after some characters, not only the space nothing works(Split for other characters).I am learning the 're' module so can you be more precise?.Thank you.

```
import re
String = "Integrity Home Care has an opening on our Leadership Team for a Salaried Private Care Nursing Supervisor.TOoooooo"
print(re.split(r'\s*',String,re.I|re.M))
```

Gives the following result:
[image: After Execution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `re.I|re.M` (10) as the value for the `maxsplit` argument, so it stops splitting after ten times, just as you told it to.

If you don't want to pass in a value for `maxsplit`, use a named argument for the flags:

```
re.split(r'\s*', String, flags=re.I|re.M)
```

Another option is not to pass the flags in as an argument but rather include them in the regular expression itself.

```
re.split(r'(?im)\s*',String)
```

I have retained the case-insensitivity flag in these examples, but your regex doesn't match any characters that could have case anyway, so you could leave it out.

Now to the regex itself. The `*` matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding pattern. This matches pretty much everywhere in the string, so in theory the string could be split anywhere, which is why you're getting that warning about non-empty patterns. These matches are ignored, but it would be better to use `+`, which means *one* or more occurrences, in its place.

Finally I would be remiss not to mention that you might be able to get away with just using `String.split()`, which splits on whitespace by default, so you could potentially do away with the regular expression.

Comment: ThankYou and can you tell me why re.I|re.M is 10 did it convert it to ascii or something like that? 
and i am getting this warning after the split:
 FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
 return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)

Comment: `re.I` is 2 and `re.I` is 8. That's how they're defined in the `re` module. The bitwise `or` of 8 and 2 is 10.

Comment: @HashikDonthineni Updated my answer to address those questions.

Answer (score 0):

`re.split(r'\s*',String,re.I|re.M)` must be `re.split(r'\s*',String,flags=re.I|re.M)`. The third positional parameter ro `re.split` is the maximal number of fragments, and you set it to `re.I|re.M`, which is 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply remove `re.I|re.M` from your code.  Try this:

```
print(re.split(r'\s',String))
```

Output:

```
['Integrity', 'Home', 'Care', 'has', 'an', 'opening', 'on', 'our', 'Leadership', 'Team', 'for', 'a', 'Salaried', 'Private', 'Care', 'Nursing', 'Supervisor.TOoooooo']
```